# Javascript documentation: Returns null or type

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a function of a js class which can return a String or `undefined`. Now I want to insert the `return` statement into the function's documentation.

```
    /**
     * Test documentation.
     * 
     * @param {(String|Number)} value - A String or a number containing a number.
     * 
     * @returns {(String|undefined)} - Returns a String or undefined.
     */
    nullOrString(value) {
        // ...
    }
```

But when I call the function, the documentation of the `return` statement only returns `String` and not `(String | undefined)`.
I also tried it with `null` instead of `undefined`, because `undefined` is returned by default by all functions without a `return` statement.

So how can I add to my documentation that a `undefined` or `null` is returned?

**EDIT:**
Add another test function.
Please notice thate these examples are test functions and do not have to make sense.

```
     /**
     * Test documentation function.
     * 
     * @param {(String|Number)} input - Input String.
     * 
     * @returns {null|undefined} - Returns null when input is numeric, otherwise returns undefined.
     */
    undefinedOrNull(input) {
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(input))) return null;
        return undefined;
    }
```

Visual studio code returns:

undefinedOrNull(input: string | number): null

Input String.

Test documentation function.

@returns — - Returns null when input is numeric, otherwise returns undefined.

Comment: What you have is correct (other than there's no reason for the `()` around `String | undefined`). What are you seeing that suggests that the return type isn't what you've defined for it? What specifically (copy and paste) is JSDoc telling you? Also, what does the content of the function look like? Some tools are smart enough to refine the type, although with an explicitly-listed type I'd expect such a tool to give you a warning on the function definition, not where you call it.

Comment: So make sure you actually return null. Maybe you always return string?

Comment: (Side note: `nullOrString` is an odd name for a method that gives you `undefined` or a string... ;-) )

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 7):

What you have there should work alright

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param value
 * @returns {string|undefined}
 */
function nullOrString(value) {
  // ...
}
```

No need for the brackets but that shouldn't matter and I think you will want a lowercase string not String.

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio Code says: nullOrString(value: any): string
@returns

Comment: Is it okay to simply write `@returns {?string}` instead?

Comment: be sure to set `strictNullChecks` to `true` - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107203#issuecomment-700208322

Answer (score 4):

be sure to set **`strictNullChecks`** to `true` in your **tsconfig.json** - otherwise, VSCode will not show `| undefined` values:

[See relevant issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107203#issuecomment-700208322)